# oscommerce postfinance integration showing unknown order/1/s

Tags: payment-gateway, oscommerce

oscommerce postfinance integration showing "unknown order/1/s"...I have already refereed `http://docs.openstream.ch/payment-provider/postfinance-error-messages/`
But it is still not working. I have used same signature for SHA-IN , SHA-OUT and in the admin side....Is this right????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by contacting post finance support.....they have asked me to select 
"Each parameters followed by pass phrase" option under Global security parameters in post finance back end. In all the documents it was given as select "main parameters only"

I hope this answer will help others.....thanks

Answer (score 1):

SHA-IN and SHA-OUT code are different strings and can be either same  or different. It is up to you. The only thing that matters is that you have to copy them precisely from your PostFinance administrator interface into your osCommerce administrator interface.

Two screenshots below are showing where SHA-IN and SHA-OUT strings are located in PostFinance administrator interface. You have to hit "Visible" button in order to see unmasked string.

[image: Srceenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: in my admin side >>>payment settings >>post finance settings there is only one option to add SHA- signature... I have added the same SHA for SHA-IN and SHA-OUT in the pot finance back end still getting the same error....In post finance back end settings under "Data and origin verification " do I need to add "URL of the merchant page containing the payment form that will call the page:orderstandard.asp "?